# How to create Database Model manually?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, npgsql

I have an existing PostgreSQL Database and I want to create the Model for a table manually because scaffolding does not work. Why does running `db.CDRs.First();` throw an exception?

Program.cs:

```
        ...
        using (var db = new Model.CDRContext())
        {
            var cdr = db.CDRs.First(); // Exception has occurred here
        }
        ...
```

CDRContext.cs:

```
    ...
public class CDRContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CallDataRecord> CDRs { get; set; }


    string DB_SERVER = "127.0.0.1";
    string USER = "x";
    string PASSWORD = "x";
    string DATABASE = "x";
    int PORT = 3306; 

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql($"Host={DB_SERVER};Username={USER}; Port={PORT};Password={PASSWORD};Database={DATABASE};");
}
    ...
```

This is the detailed exception from the debug console window:

> Unhandled exception. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "CDRs" does not exist
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>     at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
>     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
>     at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
>     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>     at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>     at EFGetStarted.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Development\EFGetStarted\Program.cs:line 17
>    Exception data:
>      Severity: ERROR
>      SqlState: 42P01
>      MessageText: relation "CDRs" does not exist
>      Position: 45
>      File: parse_relation.c
>      Line: 894
>      Routine: parserOpenTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the name of your DbSet 'CDRs' to match the name of your database table ('CallDataRecord'?) in the context. Example I've seen for PostgreSQL database first or code first are set up in this way and the error message is due to it looking for a non-existent table CDRs.

```
  public DbSet<CallDataRecord> YourDbTableName{ get; set; }
```